# How to find the username of the instance launched in amazon-ec2?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I m having trouble connecting to amazon ec2 instance using ssh. The key pair matches. 
On google-ing a bit i find that username is not the same for all instances. I assumed its always ec2-user. How can I find the username of the instance that I have launched?

I am getting this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

on trying this:

```
ssh -i test-instance.pem  ec2-user@23.22.214.148
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what AMI are you using? what is the AMI ID? Is it a custom AMI ?

Comment: It is a community AMI. debian 7 wheezy. I have also tried using root. No difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username for Debian AMI is `admin`. Read more [HERE](https://wiki.debian.org/Cloud/AmazonEC2Image/Wheezy).

Answer (score 43):

Amazon AWS has listed default usernames [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connection-prereqs.html):

> For Amazon Linux 2 or the Amazon Linux AMI, the username is `ec2-user`.
> For a CentOS AMI, the user name is `centos`.
> For a Debian AMI, the user name is `admin`.
> For a Fedora AMI, the user name is `ec2-user` or `fedora`.
> For a RHEL AMI, the user name is `ec2-user` or `root`.
> For a SUSE AMI, the user name is `ec2-user` or `root`.
> For a Ubuntu AMI, the user name is `ubuntu`.
> For an Oracle AMI, the user name is `ec2-user`.
> For a Bitnami AMI, the user name is `bitnami`.
> Otherwise, if `ec2-user` and `root` don't work, check with the AMI provider.

Comment: that's unreadable in dark mode

Comment: I'm using dark mode from SO and the text is not visible. Link of course works.

Comment: I swapped the image with just text. The original image was black-on-transparent, which looks fine in light mode, but near zero contrast in dark mode.

Comment: In case anyone was looking for the username for pfsense / freeBSD, the default username is admin

Answer (score 5):

Using AWS web console go to ec2

select `instances (running)`

select an instance by clicking in `instanceID` column

top right click on `connect`

select `ssh client` from the 4 tabs

your should see your username and instance address (and an example ssh with those details)

nb: instructions good at time of writing

Comment: Probably the most helpful answer here -- not requiring one to keep their fingers crossed that AWS doesn't change the default username.

Answer (score 4):

Get the default user name for the AMI that you used to launch your instance:

- For Amazon Linux 2 or the Amazon Linux AMI, the user name is ec2-user.
- For a CentOS AMI, the user name is centos or ec2-user.
- For a Debian AMI, the user name is admin.
- For a Fedora AMI, the user name is fedora or ec2-user.
- For a RHEL AMI, the user name is ec2-user or root.
- For a SUSE AMI, the user name is ec2-user or root.
- For an Ubuntu AMI, the user name is ubuntu.
- For an Oracle AMI, the user name is ec2-user.
- For a Bitnami AMI, the user name is bitnami.
- Otherwise, check with the AMI provider.

You can reference :  [click here for more details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connection-prereqs.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think the name is fine. The error is that you may have to change the permissions of the key with chmod 400. Then it should let you connect. If the username is wrong you'll get another error, but at least you'll have moved past this one

Answer (score 0):

Connect to AWS EC2 instance using "EC2 instance connect" option under "Connect to instance" and connect.
Inside EC2 online command prompt,

> echo ${USER}

must provide you the current user

You can also see it in command prompt (unless the name has not been changed)

> **ubuntu**@ip_address:~$

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to connect EC2 instance is

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here simple and sweet answer

Change pem file mode

```
chmod 400 my.pem
```

Access ec2 instance in terminal

```
ssh -i my.pem ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.us-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```